# SettingWithCopyWarning when using groupby and transform('first') for fillna

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, fillna

I know there are lots of similar questions. I have been trying to use them for more than an hour, but couldn't.

I have a table like the following:

| read_time | location_id | lat | lng |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-02-01 | 1 | 43 | -79.1 |
| 2019-02-01 | 2 | 43.1 | -79.4 |
| 2019-02-01 | 3 | 43 | -79.2 |
| 2020-03-01 | 2 | nan | nan |

I want to fill the empty lat and long based on the location_id. So I did so by:

```
df['lat'] = df.groupby('location_id')['lat'].transform('first')
df['lng'] = df.groupby('location_id')['lng'].transform('first')
```

and have it as follows:

| read_time | location_id | lat | lng |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-02-01 | 1 | 43 | -79.1 |
| 2019-02-01 | 2 | 43.1 | -79.4 |
| 2019-02-01 | 3 | 43 | -79.2 |
| 2020-03-01 | 2 | 43.1 | -79.4 |

But I am getting, the following warning:

```
SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

I do not want to ignore the warning, as many suggest. I would like to handle it. but I do not know how!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `pd.DataFrameGroupBy.ffill` with `bfill`:

```
>>> df = df.copy()
>>> df.loc[:, ['lat', 'lng']] = df.groupby('location_id').ffill().bfill()[['lat', 'lng']]
>>> df
    read_time  location_id   lat   lng
0  2019-02-01            1  43.0 -79.1
1  2019-02-01            2  43.1 -79.4
2  2019-02-02            2  43.1 -79.4
3  2019-02-01            3  43.0 -79.2
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks. I did not use fffil, because they are not sorted. I will update my table for clarification.

Comment: @Raha1986 Edited my answer, with both `ffill` and `bfill`, should work now

Comment: I have 20 years of data and randomly they are missing. Do you think forward or backward going to work?

Comment: @Raha1986 I do think so. You should test it

Comment: it throws the same warnings!

Comment: @Raha1986 I gotcha, check my edited answer now it shouldn't throw the warning
!

Comment: @Raha1986 Edited my answer and should work now

Comment: with this ```df = df.copy()``` all the suggested answers worked and my solutions too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236504/discussion-between-geobeez-and-u12-forward).

Comment: @U12-Forward This does not answer the question, you provided an alternative but that has nothing to do with the underlying problem. @GeoBeez: the real question is "how did you generate `df` in the first place?" The error message tells you that you're likely working with a slice and not a copy of the dataframe. Your example is not reproducible as you provided the content, not the actual state. Please provide the full code as the issue likely arises somewhere before.